# List commands require allowAdmin for redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am investigate redis connection string options in [documentation](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Configuration.html).

`var conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("redis0:6380,redis1:6380,allowAdmin=true");`

And found `allowAdmin={bool}` - *Enables a range of commands that are considered risky*

Do you know which commands are risky and required `allowAdmin=true`, besides `FlushDB`?

Thanks!

Best regards,
DarkSideMoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some period of searching in the internet I found great [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-your-redis-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04) from **digitalocean**.

In chapter - **Step 5 — Renaming Dangerous Commands** I found this risky commands:

- FLUSHDB
- FLUSHALL
- KEYS
- PEXPIRE
- DEL
- CONFIG
- SHUTDOWN
- BGREWRITEAOF
- BGSAVE
- SAVE
- SPOP
- SREM
- RENAME
- DEBUG

But article also said:

> This is not a comprehensive list, but renaming or disabling all of the
> commands in that list is a good starting point for enhancing your
> Redis server’s security.

But I think this list is enough to understand risky commands in redis.